# I want to edit this HTML design in ul li format but when I am converting its images are breakdown

Tags: html

I want to edit this HTML design in `ul` `li` format
but when I am trying to do that it goes breakdown.

```html
<body>
  <table bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1132">
    <tbody>
      <!------------------------------ START ONE ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="215" width="215">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; background-color:#332F2C; border-bottom: 1px solid #292623;" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehengas" style="text-align:center; font-size:16px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, 'Trebuchet MS'; color:#fff; text-decoration: none; padding-left: 23px; ">LEHENGA CHOLI</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; background-color:#332F2C; border-bottom: 1px solid #292623;" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehengas" style="text-decoration:none; font-size:12px;font-family:arial;padding-left:4px; color:#969696;" target="_blank">Designer Lehengas</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; background-color:#332F2C; border-bottom: 1px solid #292623;" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.fatkart.com/bollywood-lehengas" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;font-family:arial;padding-left:4px; color:#969696;" target="_blank">Bollywood Lehengas</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; background-color:#332F2C; border-bottom: 1px solid #292623;" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehenga-choli-below-3999" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;font-family:arial;padding-left:4px; color:#969696;" target="_blank">Lehengas Below Rs.3999/-</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px; background-color:#332F2C; border-bottom: 1px solid #292623;" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehenga-choli-below-4999" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;font-family:arial;padding-left:4px;; color:#969696;" target="_blank">Lehengas Below Rs.4999/-</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!---------------------------------- End First COL------------------------------------------------------------------------>
          <!------------------------------ START ---------------------------------------------------------------------->
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left:10px;" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="185">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/esha-gupta" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank"><img alt=" " border="0" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L1.jpg" style="display:block;color:#ffffff" title=" " width="185"></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <!-----------------------------End----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <!------------------------------ START ---------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left:10px" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="185">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/alia-bhatt" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank"><img alt=" " border="0" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L2.jpg" style="display:block;color:#ffffff" title=" " width="185"></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <!-----------------------------End----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <!------------------------------ START ---------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left:10px" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="185">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/kriti-sanon" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank"><img alt=" " border="0" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L3.jpg" style="display:block;color:#ffffff" title=" " width="185"></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <!-----------------------------End----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <!------------------------------ START ---------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left:10px" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="185">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/shraddha-kapoor" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank"><img alt=" " border="0" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L4.jpg" style="display:block;color:#ffffff" title=" " width="185"></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <!-----------------------------End----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say "edit this HTML design in ul li format," do you mean convert the design from a table to a list?

Comment: no i want the same in the table format. Is it possible in the UL / LI format

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking. A list inside a table? `<table><tr><td><ul><li></li></ul></td></tr></table>`

Comment: you mean, you need it in that preview without changing anything?

Comment: i want the same preview without any changes in the result.

Comment: But it should be ul - li format and within the TABLE . Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. but it needs redesigned :p

Comment: perhaps, he need e.g. list-item

Answer (score 1):

First, when you redesigned it into ul li format, you need to determine the convert many things, such as, cellpadding, cellspace, width, margin, and many more. Like I said that you need full redesign it. That means that you asked us to redesign for you?

You must provide your effort next time.

```css
ul.wow {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 23px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 215px;
}
a span.gede {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, 'liebuchet MS';
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 23px;
}
ul.wiw {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 215px !important;
}
li.ups {
  width: 215px;
  background-color: #332F2C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #292623;
}
img {
  border: 0px !important;
  max-width: 215px;
}
li.ups a {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2.500;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #969696;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wow">
  <li class="ups">
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehengas"><span class="gede">LEHENGA CHOLI</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="ups">
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehengas" style="text-decoration:none; " target="_blank">Designer Lehengas</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ups">
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/bollywood-lehengas" target="_blank">Bollywood Lehengas</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ups">
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehenga-choli-below-3999" target="_blank">Lehengas Below Rs.3999/-</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ups">
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/lehenga-choli-below-4999" target="_blank">Lehengas Below Rs.4999/-</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul class="wiw">
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/esha-gupta" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
      <img alt="" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L1.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul class="wiw">
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/alia-bhatt" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
      <img alt="" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L2.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul class="wiw">
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/kriti-sanon" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
      <img alt="" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L3.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="wiw">
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.fatkart.com/shraddha-kapoor" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
      <img alt="" height="" src="http://d66kn5h946avo.cloudfront.net//image/data/zas/menu/L4.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```